# slideup function and remove child element from parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to slide up and remove a div from within a parent but i am having a hard time figuring this out.

Here is my code if someone can help please?

```
var c = a.next(".a").nextSibling(".fav_added");
                c.length && c.slideUp(11200, function() {
                    $(this).remove()
                })
```

i have added .nextSibling but this has not worked.

i only want to remove and slideup .fav_added from within .a

Comment: What's your html? And what're you trying to do with: `c.length && c.slideUp(...)`? Is that meant to be an `if` condition of some sort? And what, precisely, *are* `a` and `c`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on "remove a div from within a parent" and ".fav_added from within .a", I'm assuming `.a` is a selector for the parent and `.fav_added` is a descendant of `.a`

In that case, what you want isn't `nextSibling()` but either `.children()` (for direct descendant) or `.find()` (to match deeper descendants as well)

```
var c = a.next(".a").find(".fav_added");
c.length && c.slideUp(11200, function() {
    $(this).remove()
})
```

Note that you can simplify it to

```
a.next('.a').find('.fav_addded').slideUp(11200, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

as checking the length is unnecessary (if c matched nothing, jQuery will execute `slideUp` on nothing).

Also, I have no idea why you use `conditional && statement` instead of `if(conditional) statement` but that makes it more confusing...